# Cannot POST /login Node.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm working with PassportJS and javascript to login and signup a new user. Then, after the signup part (which works perfectly), when I try to login I receive the page "Cannot POST /login". Can you help me understanding which is the error? Here is my code:

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var middleware =  require('../middleware');
var rootUrl = require("../../config").url;
//supported methods
router.all('/', middleware.supportedMethods('GET, OPTIONS'));
// As with any middleware it is quintessential to call next()
// if the user is authenticated
var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
res.redirect('/');
};

router.get('/library', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
     res.render('library', { user: req.user });
});

module.exports = function(passport){

/* GET login page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // Display the Login page with any flash message, if any
    res.render('library');
});

/* Handle Login POST */
router.post('/users', passport.authenticate('users', {
    successRedirect: '/library',
    failureRedirect: '/'
}));

/* GET Registration Page */
router.get('/signup', function(req, res){
    res.render('login');
});

/* Handle Registration POST */
router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
    successRedirect: '/login',
    failureRedirect: '/signup'
}));

return router;
};
```

And in the part of the dust (where I ask for the POST), I have the following code:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/standardize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body class="body login">
  <div class="vertical-align-wrapper">
    <div class="vertical-align-box">
      <h1 class="slogan">We make your <i class="fa fa-heart beats pulse" style="color:#3b7cff;"></i> beats.</h1>
      <div class="form-login-wrapper">
        <form action="/login" method="POST" class="form-login">
      <input class="form-control form-stacked" name="userName" placeholder="Username" type="text">
      <input class="form-control form-stacked last" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
      <input class="btn btn-beats btn-block btn-stacked" value="Tune in" type="submit" id="submit">
    </form>
    <p>Don't have an account? <a href="signup" class="beats"><strong>sign up</strong></a> now!   </p>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
<h1 class="fat blue-glow bottom-right">Atelier<span class="pulse" style="display:inline-block;">Beats.</span></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my login code:

```
/** @module users/router */
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var middleware =  require('../middleware');
var rootUrl = require("../../config").url;


//supported methods
router.all('/', middleware.supportedMethods('GET, OPTIONS'));

//list users
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

res.render('login');
});
/** router for /users */
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I don't see where you define a post to `/login`.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't see it either

Comment: I don't know if the problem could be in the dust (the form)

Comment: You do a redirect to /login on success but don't have login defined

Comment: If you mean as dust document, then I have it

Comment: No, in post signup. You have success redirect: '/login' witch tries to go to login page. Login route is not defined though

Comment: aaah no I have it defined in the document router.js

Comment: Can the people that put a -1 could also explain to me what the error is? Too specific question?

Comment: If there's more code to show you should show it.

Comment: @DaveNewton there are people that does not accept too much code... I don't know what I have to do in some cases

Comment: To be sure..... I also put "/" that is the equivalent to "/login"

Comment: I don't see where you define a POST to `/login` *or* where you load the login router.

Comment: How can I define a POST to /login? I don't know, maybe I define it but I don't remember how I did it because I'm working on this project since three weeks

Comment: Several projects end up in 3 weeks...

Comment: try `router.post('/login', function(req, res){})`

Comment: our project is for four weeks (in fact this is the last week)

Comment: @pp94, your `post('/users'` method looks like login. Change route to `/login` here.

Comment: done. Does not works

Comment: Please @vp_arth are you able to help me?

Comment: I can: write `router.post('/login', function(req, res){res.send(JSON.stringify(req.params);)})` for start. In Chrome developer tools you can see, that request sended, and response with json with form values received. Later you should just apply your login logic to this values.

Comment: Done in this moment. The error stays there

Answer (score 0):

Solution find:

```
/**
 * Created by test on 12.12.14.
*/
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var middleware =  require('../middleware');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
var User = mongoose.model('User');
var config = require("../../config");
var session;

router.all('/', middleware.supportedMethods('GET, POST'));
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     res.render('login');
});
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var post = req.body;
    var query = User.where({userName : post.username});
    query.findOne(function(err, user){
        if (err) { return err}
         if (user) {
             user.isValidPassword(post.password, function(n, isMatch){
                if(isMatch) {
                    req.session.user_id = user._id;
                    res.redirect('/library?' + user._id);
                } else{
                   res.redirect('/login');
               }
            });
        }else{
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    });
});

 module.exports = router;
```